# changing the background color of a item in checkbox list

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist, uibackgroundcolor

I want to change the background color of the selected item in a checkbox list.
I have tried like,

```
 CBList1.Items[0].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: red;");
```

But here the background color of the check box and the associated text is changed.
Is there any way to change just the background color of the checkbox without changing the background color of the associated text?

Comment: side note(maybe helpful for others): for Checkboxes this would be easy: `CB.InputAttributes.Add("style", "background-color: red;");` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.inputattributes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

newCkItm.Attributes.Add("id", "alpha");

That way you can keep all your styles separate from your code and not have to recompile, etc. every time you need to tweak the CSS.

With the  the CSS itself would look something like this:

```
    #cblCalendarFilter {
    border:none;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

#cblCalendarFilter td {
    padding:0;
}

#cblCalendarFilter span {
    display:block;
    padding:2px;
}

#cblCalendarFilter #alpha {
    background:red;
}

#cblCalendarFilter #beta {
    background:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think the input tag (when type=checkbox) works with the style attribute at all. Make a new checkbox input and try for yourself.

All `asp:CheckBoxList`/`asp:ItemList` and `asp:CheckBox` do is generate HTML for both the input and the label, and wrap them in a `span` tag. That span tag is where the style is being applied.

If grouping your checkboxes is not a huge concern, you can use individual `asp:CheckBox` controls with no `Text` attribute and write the associated text outside the tag.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" runat="server" />associated text 1
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb2" runat="server" />associated text 2
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb3" runat="server" />associated text 3
```

You must still call `cb1.Attributes` and not `cb1.InputAttributes` to apply the style, however.